# Why does require cause a timeout in Internet Explorer 9 when the browser console isn’t open?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, browser-console

I am maintaining a legacy web application that is built on top of the following stack:

- Server side

  - NGINX
  - Tornado
- Client side

  - RequireJS
  - jQuery
  - Backbone

Everything works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but in IE9, calling `require` inside a function to dynamically load a module causes a timeout. With the JavaScript console opened to look for errors it works fine (and there are no errors logged).

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know, but you get a (meta) +1 from me for your title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Activated developer tools usually affect your page and javascript with at least two things:
1) console.*() functions are available while dev tools are open (usually it's because of forgotten console.log() in your code. I recommend [console.log wrapper](http://paulirish.com/2009/log-a-lightweight-wrapper-for-consolelog/))
2) different than default IE rendering engine version selected. Check your Doctype and X-UA-Compatible meta tag value.

Also check this: [Does IE9 enable 'something' when using developer tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415519/does-ie9-enable-something-when-using-developer-tools)

Comment: that was it! a lone console.log... you saved my day :D

Comment: I had the same problem with a lone console.log() call. It caused more mayhem than expected in our event driven UI. IE...sigh...just....sigh...